# Applying strcpy to a pointer to array + some_offset

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

This is a language-lawyer question.

The description of `strcpy` function is given at `7.24.2.3(p2)`:

> The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including
>   the terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1.

So consider the following code:

```
char test[8] = "123";
strcpy(test + 3, "4567");
printf("%s\n", test); //1234567
```

It works as expected, but I'm confused about the object pointed to by `test + 3`. It is clear that object pointed to by `test` has declared type `char[8]`. But as far as I can see the Standard ***does not*** explicitly defined sort of this:

"If we have an array of `n` elements than a pointer to `i < n`th element can be considered a pointer to the first element of an array of `n - i` elements".

Since the function `strcpy` requires its first operand to be an array can we *pedantically speaking* apply pointer arithmetic as I showed above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Of course** `s1` does not point to an array, it points to a `char`. But the term usage comes from the [7.1.4p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p1):

> [...] If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer actually passed to the function shall have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (that would be valid if the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are in fact valid. [...]

For `strcpy(test + 3, "4567");` the accesses `test[3 + 0 ... 4]` shall be valid, which is the case, among others possibilities, if `test` is an array of at least 8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because even though the semantics of the function `strcpy` only make sense when dealing with arrays instead of pointers, there is no way for `strcpy` (or any other function) to tell whether it was passed an array or a pointer to an array, since when an array is passed as an argument to a function, it decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: This sort of argument from pragmatism makes sense, but does not seem much responsive to a [language-lawyer] question.